# UniqueEntity Symfony 3 incorrect fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, unique

I have an existing code (which perfectly works)

`* @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email", "transport"},
 *     message="Error message"
 * )`

But now I need to update this code. I want to a unique entity by 3 fields. For example - `fields={"user", "email", "transport"}`.

My question: why the second code (with 3 fields) doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#fields), when you add an Array of properties to the UniqueEntity, then it would enforce that the **combination value is unique**.

So, in your case, can exists more than one record with same email and transport if the user field is different.

If you need to require two fields to be individually unique (e.g. a unique email and a unique user), you use **two UniqueEntity entries, each with a single field**.

Comment: but if I need -> user + email + transport will be unique - how to do it?

Comment: by combination. In my table must be only one row: user=12, email=test@gmail.com, transport=113rrer454. (for example)

Comment: So, can exists another row like this? row: user=12, email=test@gmail.com, transport=114

Comment: Yes. I have two transports. So, I can have only 2 rows: 1) user=12, email=test@gmail.com, transport=transport1  2) user=12, email=test@gmail.com, transport=transport2

Comment: Then, your code seems OK... Be aware that this UniqueEnity is part of Symfony, and has nothing to do with the real persistion layer, i.e. the Database. You still can use UniqueConstraint annotation from Doctrine to create a real constraint into your DB: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint

Comment: Thank you! Works!